# Nothing has or can be given Full Disk Access after 13.2.1 Update

Tags: macos, security, bug

Following an update from macOS 13.2 to 13.2.1, all the items that had Full Disk Access have lost it (and nothing is listed as having FDA). Now new items can be added.

Is this some kind of intentional lockdown? A bug?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I guess this is just Apple testing us to see if we're paying attention?  :)

Comment: I just now upgraded a MBA and a MBP to 13.2.1 and did not experience this at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also experienced this upgrading to 13.2.1

Restart your machine (2 restarts were needed in my case).

I could not add any new items to the permissions sets for screen recording or full disk access and all previous items were no longer there (completely blank list).

After 2nd restart all previous permissions were restored and all functionality seems to be as it was.